# Integrating Stripe JS with MEAN Stack Application

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate stripe in my MEAN stack application. It's not communicating with Stripe to receive the token. I'm not sure why.

I have stripe source code sourced in my index.html page for my angular application.

It is not communicating with Stripe to receive the token, that console.log never fills, So I know it's not communicating with Stripe for some reason, but the same source code communicates with Stripe in a standalone application. I also believe it is failing when sending server side. I'm trying to send this request from port 3000 to port 8082.

Then I have the below script in another HTML page in my app for stripe:

```
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_******************');

    var $btn = $('#submit');
    $btn.on('click', function() {
        $btn.prop('disabled', true);
        $btn.button('progress');

        var cardNum = $('#card-num').val();
        var cardExp = $('#card-exp').val().split('/');
        var cardCVC = $('#card-cvc').val();

        // First submit the card information to Stripe to get back a token
        console.log("starting stripe token");
        Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: cardNum,
            exp_month: cardExp[0],
            exp_year: cardExp[1],
            cvc: cardCVC
        }, function(status, response) {
            var $form = $('#form');
            var token = response.id;
            console.log(response.id);

            // Save the token into a hidden input field
            $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

            // Now submit the form to our server so it can make the charge against the token
            $.post("http://localhost:8082/charge", $form.get(0), function(res) {
                console.log("response from charge: " + res);
            });
            // All done!
            $btn.addClass('btn-success').removeClass('btn-primary');
            $btn.button('success');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#checkout').modal('hide');
            }, 250);
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I see the console.log response of starting stripe token but it doesn't actually communicate with stripe.

Then here is my server side code:

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    // Connect to the db
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/meanAuth", function(err, db) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log("We are connected");
      }
    });
    var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
    var amount = 1000;

    stripe.charges.create({
        card: stripeToken,
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: amount
    },
    function(err, charge) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        } else {
            res.send(204);
        }
    });
});
```

My reason for doing this is I'm trying to send user information in my request to the server side code so the server can update a value in my Mongo database.

I need help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you pulling Stripe.js from Stripe, or is it packaged in your application?  It needs to come right from `https://js.stripe.com/v2/`, so that might do it.

Comment: Instead of `console.log(response.id)` which would only work on success do `console.log(response)` which might show potential errors.

Comment: I am pulling from stripe. @floatingLomas.

Comment: @Yashua That console is also blank... It's like it continously is making the request, never receiving a response

Comment: Use your bowser inspector and look at the network tab. Under 'scripts' you can verify that stripe is loaded and under XHR you should see the outgoing requests.

Comment: @Yashua I see it in sources, not under network though

Comment: Sounds like Chrome? So nothing under Network->XHR when you click the button? And when you click on that script in Sources you can see its content yes? Do you have any kind of Mocks running in Angular? or some kind of http code that might be intercepting?

Comment: Yes it is chrome. Also, Yes I can see the contents of stripe in the developer tools. And no not that I can think of that should be intercepting it. @Yashua

Comment: If you can post the entire controller it might help a bit. No need for server code as its not relevant to this issue. I am able to get a response from Stripe using the same code as above but it sounds like you can too, just not in an Angular scenario?  Are you loading Stripe before anything other scripts in your index file?

Comment: @Yashua Yes they are other scripts being loaded before and after Stripe.JS. Could the issue be that this script is not running in its own directive?

Comment: Its unclear but to be safe put stripe before any angular code. Some setups will stub Stripe (make a fake Stripe object until loaded). Not sure it will help but its worth trying.